# angular js - scope.apply not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular material 1 and want to hide sidenave when window size not satisfy "gt-sm". Below is the controller code.

```
 .controller('mainpageController',mainpageAction);

function mainpageAction($scope,$mdMedia,$window){
    //state variable for mainpage.
    $scope.sideNavVisibility = $mdMedia('gt-sm');

    /* function definition for mainpage; bind this function using ng-click when user click on side menu */
    $scope.showSideNav = function(defaultDisplay){
        $scope.sideNavVisibility = true;
    };
    angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
        console.log($mdMedia('gt-sm'));
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.sideNavVisibility = $mdMedia('gt-sm');
        });
    });
}
```

Below is the HTML template where I am using it.

```
<body md-theme="mainpage" ng-controller="mainpageController">
<div layout="row" layout-fill="true">
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-is-locked-open="{{sideNavVisibility}}" flex="none">
```

In console I am getting the correct value. When screen side is greate than 960px it is logging "true" value else "false". But still the change is not getting applied to view.

**Here basically I want to show sidenav if screen size is more than 960px i.e. "gt-sm" or when not greater than "gt-sm" then when user click on side menu icon.**

Comment: If you simply want to show/hide then you should be using `ng-show` or `ng-hide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double curly brackets `{{ }}` from the expression furnished to the `md-is-locked-open` attribute:

```
<body md-theme="mainpage" ng-controller="mainpageController">
    <div layout="row" layout-fill="true">
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left"
                <!-- REMOVE double curly brackets 
                md-is-locked-open="{{sideNavVisibility}}"
                -->
                md-is-locked-open="sideNavVisibility"                     
                flex="none">
```

Double curly brackets converts the boolean value `false` to the string `"false"`. In JavaScript the string `"false"` is truthy instead of falsy. In fact any string with a length greater than zero is truthy. This is one of the quirks of JavaScript.

For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference - falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 0):

To show/hide an element based on a condition in Angular you can simply use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide).

```
<md-sidenav ng-show="sideNavVisibility" class="md-sidenav-left" flex="none">
```

Comment: Thanks .. but I don't want side menu to overlap contents at the same moment of time.

Comment: In your own words "...basically I want to show sidenav if..." You need to be more clear with your requirements and/or provide more code.

Comment: In your code it looks like you are using Angular with an attribute for some other code. My guess is you need to re-run your code which handles the nav when `sideNavVisibility` changes.

Comment: sideNavVisibility is changing on window resize to true and false and as per above code i have already bound it. Still it is not getting applied.

Comment: No errors in console? If it's on window resize you should probably use `$timeout` instead of `$apply`.

Comment: no.no error at console. I am getting proper value of "sideNavVisibility" while debugging $scope Batarang. Also tried with "$setTimeout(function () {},10);", but no luck. Here basically I want to show sidenav if screen size is more than 960px i.e. "gt-sm" or when not greater than "gt-sm" then when user click on side menu icon. On loading the screen at different window size all works fine but not with resize.